# Why is the name of head bolditalic?

Tags: theorems

I have the following LaTeX source code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[serbianc,serbian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Теорема}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Прва глава}

\section{Прва секција}

\begin{thm}\label{testthm}
Нека ред $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ конвергира и наке функције $f_n(x)$ 
имају непрекидне изводе
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

After running XeLaTeX I get PDF file

[image]

Unfortunately  the name of theorem (Теорема) is bolditalic. 
My goal is the name of theorem should be bold `\bfseries` and  the font in the body of the theorem `\itshape`.  If someone knows the solution, please help me. Thank in advance.

Comment: If you comment the lines `\usepackage{polyglossia}` and `\usepackage{polyglossia}`, you get the header in upshape as expected.

Comment: Why do you use both polyglossia and babel?

Comment: Opened an issue at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new theorem style using `\newtheoremstyle`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[serbianc,serbian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
%\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{amsthm}

% Pick a better name
\newtheoremstyle{requestedstyle}% name
  {3pt}% Space above
  {3pt}% Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}% Indent amount, empty means none
  {\upshape\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {.}% Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}% Space after theorem head
  {}% Theorem head spec, empty means normal
\theoremstyle{requestedstyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Теорема}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Прва глава}

\section{Прва секција}

\begin{thm}\label{testthm}
Нека ред $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ конвергира и наке функције $f_n(x)$
имају непрекидне изводе
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't have the font you're using but I do have Arial.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad interaction between `fontspec` and `polyglossia`; what happens is that `\normalfont` doesn't really pick up the main document font (for Serbian), as you can see in the “Test” line, which has bold italic rather than bold upright.

You can cure the specific problem by adding `\upshape` in the default `\thm@headfont` token list.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[
  Script=Cyrillic,
  Language=Serbian,
]

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\makeatletter
\thm@headfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Теорема}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Прва глава}

\section{Прва секција}

{\itshape\normalfont\bfseries Test} % is italic!

\begin{thm}\label{testthm}
Нека ред $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ конвергира и наке функције $f_n(x)$ 
имају непрекидне изводе
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]